# Is it possilbe to set altField property of persian datepicker dynamically from data-altFiled property?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Is it possible to set `altField` property of [persian datepicker](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/) from `data-altFiled` property of the element instead of setting it like `'#elementId'` or `'.className'` ?

I have tried so far:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BirthDate, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
<input class="pDate form-control" autocomplete="off" data-altField="BirthDate" />

$('.pDate').pDatepicker({
    observer: true,
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    initialValue: false,
    autoClose: true,
    altField: $(this).data('altField'), // this is the line that is supposed to be dynamic!
    altFieldFormatter: function (unixDate) {
         var date = new Date(unixDate);
         return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
    }
});
```

It seems that `$(this)` does not refer to the element! any suggestions?

**** additional info:** there are several inputs with `'.pDate'` class on the page and each of them has its own `altfield`

Comment: try $(".pDate").data('altField')

Comment: @EvikGhazarian that won't work when there are several inputs with '.pDate' class, would it?

Comment: Roozbeh jan , lol , can you explain more which part you have problem with? altField: $(this).data('altField') this line?

Comment: Evik jan ;) it seems that $(this) in this scenario does not refer to the element but rather to the document. so $(this).data(...) will not return valid data

Answer (score 0):

You can do Something like this:

```
$('input[data-altField=Birthdate]').pDatepicker({
    observer: true,
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    initialValue: false,
    autoClose: true,
    altField: $(this).data('altField'), // this is the line that is supposed to be dynamic!
    altFieldFormatter: function (unixDate) {
         var date = new Date(unixDate);
         return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
    }
});
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
$("input[data-altField=somevalue]").on('keyup',function(){
$(".msg").append("<p>something typed</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="someid" data-altField="somevalue">

<div class="msg"></div>
```